# How to sum values in list of csv values in Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I have a list of name comma seperated name value pairs where some are repeating :

```
10, test1
11, test2
12, test3
13, test1
14, test2
```

I would like to sum the values (in descending order) that are repeating so above list becomes :

```
25, test2
23, test1
12, test3
```

In java I would create a new list and iterate over the existing list. Each element in the list will be compared to every other element, if any name matches then the values are summed and once the end of the list is reached then this new element is added to the new list. If no element matches (the element is unique) then this element is added with its value. Once finished I would use some kind of comparator to sort the List.

Is there a more functional way to achieve this in Scala, possible using filter method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have parsed your CSV in something like this:

```
val data = List((10, "test1"), (11, "test1"), ...)
```

You can now do:

```
data.groupBy(_._2).map {
  case (label, vals) => (vals.map(_._1).sum, label)
}.toList.sortBy(_._2)
```

This does it all.

Answer (score 1):

You could first use a [`groupBy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) to collect the values into a map, then use [`mapValues`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map) to compute the answer you need, which is just sum in this example.

Also note that here the team names is key and the sum is value, but that should not really matter (?) .